# Digital signature when only one person has public/private key

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, digital-certificate, electronic-signature

Hello I have a scenarios where a client and a bank must communicate in a secure way and they must use electronic signature but only the bank has public/private key. How will the communication occur? Meaning how will they authenticate each other who will give the key to who how will the encryption occur?

Answer (score 0):

It can't. The bank must have a pair of key (private and public) representing the bank, and the client must also have a pair of keys representing the client. If only the bank has a pair of key only the banks identity can be verified. Example: the bank sends a public message to all clients and signs it with its private key. All the clients can by using the banks public key indeed verify that the message comes from the bank.
 However a client can also send an encrypted message to the bank using the banks public key, and only the bank can indeed read this message by using its private key, but the bank can not determine the identity of the client.
The clients identity can of course be determined by other means for instance by a login credentials.

Comment: What if the client verifies his identity with username & password? @user2304458

Comment: @Zio Toto  That will do, I just added that to my answer:)

Comment: Okay thank you! Can you please be more specific with the part how the bank signs it and how the digital signature works if possible? Cause I've been reading around but stillhave some doubts

Comment: Does the bank sends its public key first or what?

Comment: It is really a question about math. . 
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/A_Basic_Public_Key_Example

Comment: @Zio Toto Yes its public key is public. I am not sure how it is published it depends on the application. What if someone trick the client to use a false public key, well then the client will end up sending a message to the bank which the bank can decrypt and will hopefull inform the client about it.

Comment: What if the scenario is for a client and a bank server who need to communicate with encrypted messages but only the server has a digital certificate? What happens in this case? How does the communication happen?

Comment: One way could be:The clients browser gets the public key from the cerificate and send en encrypted message to the server with login credentials and a generated public key just for the client and just for the communication.
The bank decrypts it (with its private key) and has now determined the clients identity. It sends an encrypted welcome screen to the client using the received public key. The client can decrypt it by using the generated private key. And this can go on and on.

Comment: Ok so the client just generates a public/private key and uses it?

Comment: My last comment will work, but the communication between the client and the bank can be more simple. The client sends it credentials and a suggested encrypting scheme to the bank. The suggested scheme does not have to depend on a public/private key.